# java - How to open server socket again after closing it ?

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

I'm using ServerSocket object in my project. Basically, I have a button which closes socket and open it again. How can I do this ? I can close socket. However, cannot open it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not do that, take a look to the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html)

particullarly this line:

> Once a socket has been closed, it is not available for further
>   networking use (i.e. can't be reconnected or rebound). A new socket
>   needs to be created.

-

---

> close
>
> public void close()
>              throws IOException Closes this socket. Any thread currently blocked in an I/O operation upon this socket will throw a
>   SocketException.
>
> Once a socket has been closed, it is not available for further
>   networking use (i.e. can't be reconnected or rebound). A new socket
>   needs to be created.
>
> Closing this socket will also close the socket's InputStream and
>   OutputStream.
>
> If this socket has an associated channel then the channel is closed as
>   well.
>
> Throws: IOException - if an I/O error occurs when closing this socket.
>   See Also: isClosed()